# How to slice a list from an element n to the end in python?

Tags: python, list, sequence, slice

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to slice python lists, it is illustrated as follows:

```
>>> test = range(10)
>>> test
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> test[3:-1]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> test[3:0]
[]
>>> test[3:1]
[]
>>> test
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

To my understanding, python slice means lst[start:end], and including start, excluding end. So how would i go about finding the "rest" of a list starting from an element n?

Thanks a lot for all your help!

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You can leave one end of the slice open by not specifying the value.

```
test[3:] = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
test[:3] = [0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 130):

If you're using a variable as the range endpoint, you can use `None`.

```
 start = 4
 end = None
 test[start:end]
```

Comment: Oh thank you! i was looking for this, but didn't know how to search for it :). I feel the accepted answer is sort of incomplete without this, because leaving an end index is trivial and has enough documentation.

Comment: This same technique is also very useful to do the same thing with slice(4, None), where the colon approach does not work.

Answer (score 20):

Simply omit the end.

```
test[n:]
```

Answer (score 5):

Leaving out the end still works when you want to skip some:

```
range(10)[3::2] => [3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 3):

Return a slice of the list after a starting value:

```
my_list = ['a','b','c','d']
start_from = 'b' # value you want to start with
slice = my_list[my_list.index(start_from):] # returns slice from starting value to end
```

Comment: Even though this is example code, it's best not to use `list` as a variable name

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [**`None`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.NoneType) keyword for the *end* parameter when slicing. This would also return the elements till the end of the list (or any *sequence* such as tuple, string, etc.)

```
# for list
In [20]: list_ = list(range(10))    
In [21]: list_[3:None]
Out[21]: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

# for string
In [22]: string = 'mario'
In [23]: string[2:None]
Out[23]: 'rio'

# for tuple
In [24]: tuple_ = ('Rose', 'red', 'orange', 'pink', 23, [23, 'number'], 12.0)
In [25]: tuple_[3:None]
Out[25]: ('pink', 23, [23, 'number'], 12.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is to use something like:

```
inputs = "ababbbaAab"
for i in range(n):
    print(i, inputs[:i] + inputs[i:i+1])
```

The output:

```
0 a
1 ab
2 aba
3 abab
4 ababb
5 ababbb
6 ababbba
7 ababbbaA
8 ababbbaAa
9 ababbbaAab
```

See that if `i == 0`

then `inputs[:i] == []` and `inputs[i:i+1] == a`

and if `i == len(inputs) - 1`

then `inputs[:i] == [ababbbaAa]` and `inputs[i:i+1] == b`