# List slice from _nth_ to last element

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

This is what I have so far.

```
print(listTest[3: ])
```

I am just unsure what to put on the other side of the semicolon. -1 gives me one less index then the answer. So I am asking how to get the true end of the list.

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python list slicing", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to slice a list from an element n to the end in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621354/how-to-slice-a-list-from-an-element-n-to-the-end-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

`listTest[3:]`

Not having anything after the `:` means *until the end of the list*.

Answer (score 1):

You can either put **length of the array**

```
listTest[3:len(listTest)]
```

OR

Leave it **empty**

```
listTest[3:]
```